# Run a rake task rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I am trying to get a rake task to run, basically a screen grab and then post the data to a model. I have a task but not sure on how to get it to run

```
namespace :grab do
task :fixtures => :environment do
MatchFixtures::MatchFixtures.new.perform
end
end
```

Im way out here  but i thought it was

```
rake namespace:task
```

but i get

```
dont know how to build task 'namespace:task'
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to substitute your own namespace/tasks in there, so:

```
rake grab:fixtures
```